# Not able to connect mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, sockets, ubuntu

Not able to connect MySQL... detail given bellow.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 202
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /var/www/html/application/controllers/Account.php
> Line: 7
> Function: __construct
>
> File: /var/www/html/index.php
> Line: 315
> Function: require_once

Comment: Your MySQL server isn't running, has crashed, or doesn't create a sock file where you think it does.

Comment: sock file is exist on path ...but I am not able to start MySQL service.... when I going to start services its giving above error

Comment: Existing and being operational are two different things. Are you sure your process has permission to access it? Can you connect over IP instead?

Comment: No, I am not sure. If there is any way to check this ? And how I solved this Error ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download xampp and ensure that my sql services on or off .if it is on then you are write function mysqli_connect(‘localhost’,’username’,’password’,’database’);

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a xampp installed in your system and SQL service was enabled.
If yes, then create one database file in your application/config folder. Filename is database.php
Here you need to give a default db driver variable, likewise

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'your-db-username',
    'password' => 'your-db-password',
    'database' => 'your-db-name',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8mb4',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Next, you need to load this database.php config file in autoload.php (in the same directory).

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Now, you have connected a database with your Codeigniter project.

> Reference : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/configuration.html